Signal , discrete , random, independent
Let $x(n)$ be a discrete, random independent process, with Gaussian distribution with mean value $\mu_x = 1$ and standard deviation $ \sigma_x = 3$.

Compute the probability that $x(n) < 0$ and the power of the process.
Compute and plot the autocorrelation and the power spectrum density of $x(n)$.
Let $z$ be the process: $z(n) = y(n-1) + y(n+1)$. Compute its mean value, power, autocorrelation, and power spectrum density.
Compute the probability distribution of $z$.


Hi and welcome. We don't  give complete solutions to homework problems. Please let us know where what you have tried and where specifically you are stuck
